# Как реализовать появление элементов при прокрутке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Задача стоит простая, реализовать плавное появление блоков при прокрутке.

Уже по разному пытался. Работает только вариант с прямым прописыванием поведения блока в jquery-CSS. НО!!! Меня интересует почему добавление класса Animate.css не срабатывает? При этом не пойму, надо ли скрывать изначально элемент, потому как если не показывать, то прокрутка едет прерывистая, с задержками.

Сильно ногами не пинать. Если допустил ошибку в оформлении прошу вежливо указать.

Просто уже застрял второй день на этом, все что можно было просмотреть по теме, просмотрел, и видео и статьи, и на русском и на английском.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#bootstrap-block').each(function(){
          if ($(window).scrollTop()>50) {
            $(this).toggleClass('animated fadeUp');
          }
        });
      });
```

Пишу на сайте "Кодручка.ои".

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.mov').each(function(){
   var blockPos = $(this).offset().top;
   var topWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (blockPos < topWindow+300){
      $(this).addClass('fadeUp')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">Example
    <div class="col-md-12 animated">Example</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте [эту статью](http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery) 

 По сути надо просто подключить небольшую js библиотеку и она сама будет отлавливать момент появления обьекта, которому вы присвоите класс, в поле видимости пользователя. 
А насчет плавности и скрытия, то элементу не стоит прописывать `display:none;` или `.hide()` , но надо прописать `opacity:0;` с дальнейшим изменением на 1(если приписавать весь css самому то следует также указывать и transition и т.д. но думаю вы это все знаете), это позволит отработывать начальному смещению блока за пределы видимости пользователя и потом плано появляться.